# ModelState is returning error when the data is correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that returns the select data that I'm looking for when I create a new entry. This has worked before when I was doing the create process all server-side, but now that I'm moving the website over to client-side it returns an error saying it can't convert string to int. Before the statement

```
if (ModelState.IsValid){
 //Do stuff
}
```

I convert the string to a int32 to match the database and store it to a list called lansing and then to the column TripType so it would look like `lansing.TripType = Convert.ToInt32(triptype);`

Any form of insight onto either cause the ModelState to reevaluate or why it would be throwing such an error to begin with.

Comment: Maybe what you could do is check in the request which value is coming for the field you expect. Probably is coming null/empty, could be some client side error. Also you can check if there is any JavaScript error client side (in the browser console)

Comment: Can you share the code of your input & associated class?

Comment: @Melchia this is what I'm using for the user to select a value `<select class="required" name="Trip" id="trip"><option value="">Please Select an option</option> <option value="1">One Way</option><option value="2">Round Trip</option></select>` I'm also using `string triptype = Request.Form["Trip"];`

Comment: @CicheR I have double checked and there are no errors or returning of a null occurring that could be causing this.

Comment: Silly question, but just in case: _is your `select` inside the `<form>` that you are submitting?_ 

Comment: @CicheR yes it is inside a  `@Html.BeginForm()`